# Prefetch_related() join all on first item

Tags: python, django

I'm almost sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure it out.

In my app, Items can be stored in Workspaces, as follows :

```
# models.py    
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Workspace(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField()
    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        Item,
        related_name="workspaces",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None)
```

Then, in my ListView, I want to display Items, and their related workspaces:

```
# views.py
class ListItems(ListView):
    model = Items
    template_name = "list_items.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all().prefetch_related('workspaces')
```

The bug occurs in my template:

```
# list_items.html
{% for object in object_list %}

    {{ object.name }}
    Workspaces : 
    {% for workspace in object.workspaces.all %}
        {{ workspace.name }}
    {% empty %}
        No workspaces
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let's say I have 10 different Items, and a single folder called "Foo". Instead of displaying my template like this:

```
Item1
workspaces: Foo

Item2
workspaces: Foo

Item3
workspaces: Foo

#etc...
```

I get the following output :

```
Item1
workspaces: Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo # 1 Foo per item in list

Item2
workspaces: No workspaces

Item3
workspaces: No workspaces

#etc...
```

It seems like prefetch_related() associates all workspaces to the first item in list.
If I remove the prefetch_related() part of  get_queryset(), I get the right output, but it takes more queries.

What am I doing wrong here ?

My app is far more complex, so maybe I simplified it too much. Especially, my get_queryset() method involve more filters before the prefetch_related() instruction.
Just tell me if you need more data.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Did you test your sample code? ...I run it with Django 1.5.1 but can't generate the problem you described, got `item1 worspace: Foo, item2 workspace: Foo, ...`, maybe the error is introduced in a line removed when simplify your code

Comment: Post the code that is giving you the problem instead of the simplification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll give you more informations soon. Posting the whole code would be difficult, because the application is complex (multilevel inheritance for views, models, etc.). Since Juliocesar has tested the code and can't reproduce the issue, it must lies in my own logic. What I can do is give you access to the git repo (nothing private in it), but you'll have to set up the whole project, explore the code, etc, which can require some time. I'd be glad to get closer help, but don't feel forced to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I forgot a very important element : I'm using django-polymorphic for my base model. 
I've run som
e tests and without polymorphic, `prefetch_related` works as expected.

I've opened an issue in django-polymorphic bug tracker : https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic/issues/68

I really apologize for that mistake, and I'm sorry for losing your time.